# how to import a variable in if __name__ == '__main__': of a python file to other python file?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to get a variable present in the " `if __name__ == '__main__':` " of `py1.py` file to `py2.py`. I tried doing

```
from py1 import x
```

and

```
import py1
```

but they are not working. Am I doing something wrong?
here is an example of what i am doing:

py1.py :

```
def func1():
    return some_list_as_result

if __name__ == '__main__': 
     x = func1()
```

py2.py:

```
from py1 import x
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare that variable as global to import it in antoher file:

```py
def func1():
    return some_list_as_result

x = func1()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
.
.
.
```

Doesn't look very elegant, so in this case it will be better if you import `func1` in the other file.

As a note the code inside a main only executes when you call directly the script. It doesn't run when you import the file, so in this case variable `x` doesn't even exists when you do the import.